# OpenCV capture code freezes when it is called in system function

Tags: c, opencv, pthreads, system

I am developing an application in OpenCV. I am taking a snapshot from camera and then I am closing the capture.

Here below my capture code (capturecam1lowres.c)

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
  CvCapture* camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(0); // Use the default camera

  IplImage*     frame = 0;

  cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024) ;
  cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768); 

  frame = cvQueryFrame(camera); //need to capture at least one extra frame
//  frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);

  if (frame != NULL) {
    printf("Frame extracted from CAM1\n\r");
        cvSaveImage("/home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/webcam1.jpg", frame,0);
  } else {
      printf("Null frame 1\n\r");
  }
  cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
  cvReleaseImage(&frame);
  return 0;
}
```

I am calling this code's executable from 
    system(./capturecam1lowres) 
but it freezes in the

```
frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);
```

line sometimes (not every time). How can I set a timeout for this sub program (capturecam1lowres). If capture takes too much time, it should give up and exit. How can I achieve that?

I tried to use a posix thread but could not achieved the result. Here below my non working threaded code also.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg) 
 {

    sleep(10);
    exit(0);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
  CvCapture* camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(0); // Use the default camera
  pthread_t mythread;
  IplImage*     frame = 0;

  if ( pthread_create( &mythread, NULL, thread_function, NULL) ) 
  {
    printf("error creating thread.");
    abort();
  }

  if ( pthread_join ( mythread, NULL ) ) 
  {
    printf("error joining thread.");
    abort();
  }


  cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024) ;
  cvSetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768); 

  frame = cvQueryFrame(camera); //need to capture at least one extra frame
//  frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);

  if (frame != NULL) {
    printf("Frame extracted from CAM1\n\r");
        cvSaveImage("/home/root/Desktop/BBTCP/webcam1.jpg", frame,0);
  } else {
      printf("Null frame 1\n\r");
  }
  cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
  cvReleaseImage(&frame);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure but you execute this program in another programm embeded? This program may block if the stdout or errout buffer is full and is not readed by the *executing* application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in the code or system design but the problem is at the DMA module of embedded system itself. Corruption at DMA bulk transfer, causes this error. So there are no software problem.